# Doctrine N + 1 problem with nested one-to-one relationships

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I'm encountering the dreaded N+1 problem using Doctrine, specifically when fetching tables with bidirectional one-to-one relationships. I now understand that bidirectional one-to-one relationships should be avoided in Doctrine, but I'm working on an old codebase and I want to change as little as possible since I don't know if there could be side effects.

## Context

I have an `Intervention` table, with a Many-To-One relationship with the `User` table. The `User` table has a One-To-One relationship with the `UserIdentity` table. The relationship is mapped by `User`, and inversed by `UserIdentity`

## The problem

I encounter the N+1 problem when trying to query the `Intervention` table and joining the `User` relation. For every unique `User`, a query is made to fetch a corresponding `UserIdentity`. This leads to about 1K unique queries.

I have faced a similar problem before, and solved it by adding the inverse side of the One-To-One relation to my SELECT call, and LEFT JOIN-ing it. However in this case it does not seem to work.
I suspect this is because `UserIdentity` is not a direct association of `Intervention`, but of `User` instead.

## What I tried

Here's what my code looks like thus far. I've trimmed everything that's irrelevant to the problem.

```
        $alias = "intervention";

        $qb = $this->manager
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("partial $alias .{id, uuid, purpose, type, creation, detectorUuid}, intervention_user, trackdechetsIdentity, fibsd")
        ->from(Intervention::class, $alias)
    ;

    $qb = $qb
        ->leftJoin("$alias.user", 'intervention_user')
        ->leftJoin("intervention_user.trackdechetsIdentity", "trackdechetsIdentity") // This is the UserIdentity entity
        ->leftJoin("$alias.fibsd", "fibsd") // Solving another N+1 problem, this time it's a direct one-to-one relation
        ->orderBy("$alias.id", 'DESC')
    ;
    
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This generates about as many queries as there are users in my database.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question.

I still don't know why I can't resolve this the way I did with a direct one-to-one relationship. However, using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723798/22107814) did just fine.

By changing the relationship from One-To-One to a Many-To-One/One-To-Many allows for lazy loading and gets rid of the N+1 problem. See the linked answer for more explanation